# Multiple initial for checkbox rendered using widget-tweaks

Tags: django, modelchoicefield

I need guidance in selecting multiple initial values for checkbox which are rendered using widget-tweaks.

My code is working great when I have a single initial value. However when there is more than 1 initial value, only the first will be checked in the checkbox.

forms.py

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('name', 'category', 'pods')

    def __init__(self, group_id, category_id, *args, **kwargs):           
        super(GroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        selected_group = Group.objects.get(id=group_id) 
        self.fields['name'].initial = selected_group.name
        self.fields['category'].initial = selected_group.category.id
        self.fields['pods'].queryset = Pod.objects.filter(category=selected_group.category.id)
        associated_pods = selected_group.pod.all()  
        self.fields['pods'].initial = [pod.id for pod in associated_pods]
```

views.py

```
def GroupUpdate(request,id):
    group = get_object_or_404(Group, pk=id)
    context = {}
    group_id = group.id
    category_id = request.GET.get('category')
    context['form'] = GroupForm(group_id, category_id)
    return render(request, 'catalog/group_detail.html', context)
```

html file

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Group's Members</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="input-group btn-group">
           <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i>
           </span>
           {% render_field form.pods|attr:"multiple:multiple"|attr:"data-plugin-multiselect" title="group_member" class="form-control" %}
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

I need the pre-selected initial values of the checkbox to be rendered dynamically.
Currently self.fields['pods'].initial = [pod.id for pod in associated_pods] will only tick one checkbox although there is more than one associated pods.

Answer (score 0):

I think I made some progress in my investigation. This jquery data-plugin-multiselect somehow only accepts single initial value. Perhaps anybody knows how to tweak this jquery to be able to accept multiple initial values.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by adding widget to the form

```
pods = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Pod.objects.all(),
    required=False,
    empty_label=None,
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
)
```